# Listview in c# windows forms app. how can i add a value for each column?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

i'm trying for a while to add some values in a Listview form an array with 6 elements. The thing is i have to have them on 6 different columns with their pozitiont in the array above them. like this:
0 || 1 || 2 ||...
23|| 5 || -2||...

my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                contor = i;
                lista.View = View.Details;
                lista.Columns.Add(contor.ToString());
                lista.Items.Add(CALCUL[i].ToString());
            }
```

shows like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as6la.png)

Comment: Do you mean the _text alignment_ in each column? That should be the `ListViewColumn.Align` property.

Comment: Use a DataGridView. It's a lot more intuitive

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want but that is how you can add columns and rows:

```
listView1.View = View.Details;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
   listView1.Columns.Add("C"+i);
}
listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[]{ "A","B","C","D","E","F" }));
```

[looks like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKGYy.png)